# Connecting Second Switch to Primary?

Tags: networking, switch

My broadband internet connection goes from a cable to a combo switch/router/wlan supplied by the phone company that has 4 outgoing ethernet ports.  I have two of these connected directly to PCs and it works fine.

One of the ethernet cables is very long and runs down to the office PC.

I now want to setup a third machine located in the office.

The plan is to purchase a `Cisco SD2008T, 8 Port Gigabit Ethernet Switch` for the office, and two more short ethernet cables.

I will connect the two office machines to the new switch and then connect this switch with a long cable to the main router/switch.

**My question is do I need a crossover ethernet cable to connect the two switches, or will the existing long straight ethernet cable work fine?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long, straight cable will work fine. All modern switches have [auto-MDI/X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto-MDIX).

> Automatic MDI/MDI-X cable detection adjusts for different cable types currently in use on your network. - 
>   [Amazon.com page for SD2008T](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BVK7NU)

You should never use crossover cables with Gigabit ports unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You only need a Crossover Cable to connect two PCs directly without a switch in between. And most NICs don't even need that anymore. For you switch just use a standard LAN cable.
Unless "very long" does not mean more than 100 metres you should be good there as well.